# How to enable SSL for Angular App in subdirectory?

Tags: angular, typescript, ssl, web-deployment

I have deployed an Angular Application to a subdirectory as [www.mywebsite.com/my-app-here](http://www.mywebsite.com/my-app-here).

When the user enters [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com), I see the green lock as the SSL is enabled here. But when the user enters or navigates to /my-app-here, the lock dissapers and the page is "not secure".

Comment: SSL is already enabled for your subdirectory. You just have to enforce it by redirecting all HTTP traffic to HTTPS. This is done in various ways depending on the hosting environment and platform the applications are built on.

Comment: Thank you Cap, I will try diving deeper into the hosting enviroment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Captain Kenpachi answered:

> SSL is already enabled for your subdirectory. You just have to enforce
> it by redirecting all HTTP traffic to HTTPS. This is done in various
> ways depending on the hosting environment and platform the
> applications are built on.

I just had to redirect all http-requests to https-request for the specific route. (I ended up redirecting all routes).